# Constelation rotation, scaling and cyclic Q delay in python

Tags: python-3.x, dvb-t

I want to rotate, scale (normalize) and cyclic Q delay (shift) QAM costelation in python.

I wrote transmitter and receiver function to rotate and scale input constelation by given values( based on DVB-T2 standard)

I am having problems with cyclic Q delay(also called shifting). 
Given standard specifies those operation by this formula
[formula from dvb-t2 standard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mYCO.png)

My transmitter function looks like this:

```
def transmitter_rotation_and_Qdelay(phase_deg, r_phasor, input_constelation, number_of_points_in_constelation): 
phasor_norm, phasor_mod = phasor_normalization(phase_deg, r_phasor) # function to change phazor to phasor_norm - e^jfi2 phasor_mod - r

g_out_array = np.zeros(number_of_points_in_constelation, dtype=complex) 
iterator = 0
for i in input_constelation:
    in_mod = np.abs(i)  # abs from input conselation point gives this r*e^jfi
    in_norm = i / in_mod  # in_norm - e^jfi
    g_out_array[iterator] = (in_norm * phasor_norm) * (in_mod * phasor_mod) # implementation of formula from standard
    iterator = iterator + 1
```

So my question is:
How to propely perform shift in constelation using python and how perform reverse operation?

EDIT

After some time i figured out that, to implement mentioned formula i only need to(i think) shift complex values in constelation.

I tried doing it this way:

```
    shifted_input_constelation = np.real(input_constelation) + np.roll(np.imag(input_constelation), 1)
```

Here appears problem.

shifted array changes its values to those

```
 0000 = {float64} -1.2649110640673518
 0001 = {float64} 0.0
 0002 = {float64} -1.8973665961010275
 0003 = {float64} -1.2649110640673518
 0004 = {float64} 0.0
```

Is there way to shift complex values in array using methonds from numpy?

Comment: If you were able to implement rotating and scaling, what exactly is the problem when you try to implement shifting?

Comment: rotating and scaling constelations was much easier to do. I simply changed phasor and complex values from constelation from representation x+iy to e^jfi representation and multiplied them. Problem is that i dont know how to implement shifting. I tried to use "numpy.roll" for that but it just shifts elements of conselation. They need to muliplied in specific way defined in given formula. How to use this formula when all of my data is in  form of e^jfi?